# Цикличная прокрутка bg по вертикали

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, анимация

Есть следующий код, надо сделать так, чтобы фон циклично прокручивался по вертикали без швоф.

```css
.bg {
  -moz-animation: bg 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bg 5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: bg 5s linear infinite;
  animation: bg 5s linear infinite;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/39/rain-316580_960_720.jpg") bottom left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% {
      -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
      -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1920px,0);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1920px,0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1920px,0);
      transform: translate3d(0,1920px,0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мы должны аннимировать **background-position**

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}

#bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://mobilegamegraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Untitled-3.jpg') repeat-y;
    background-size:100% 50%;
    animation: changewidth linear 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes changewidth {
    from { background-position-y: 0; }
    to { background-position-y: -100%}
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
```

Comment: здесь более человечный пример : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oqzjpv

Comment: скажу больше что анимирование background-position работает ни везде